# What is the underlying type of the result from a Linq to Entities query?

Tags: asp.net, linq

for example,

```
var result = from category in myEntities.Categories
                     where category.UserId == userId
                     orderby category.CategoryName
                     select category;
```

What is the type of "result"? I casted it to an IQueryable variable and it worked except it did not have some of the methods normally available, e.g. Count(). In my program I have to cast it to some explicit types and then use the Count() method. What should I do?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your question is not unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
IQueryable<Category> categories = from x category in myEntities.Categories
                                  where category.UserId == userId
                                  orderby category.CategoryName
                                  select category;
```

I don't see why count would be unavailable in this scenario. Maybe if you were casting to plain `IQueryable` and not `IQueryable<Category>`?

**EDIT:** Just tested it. It's definitely because you used a generic IQueryable without a type. .Count() is not available when you use that. You must include the type.

**EDIT2:** If you are creating an anonymous type then you have to use the var keyword. You will need to create a type in order to cast it.

Create a custom type like this:

```
public class MyCustomType
{
     public string CategoryName { get; set; }
     public int UserId { get; set;}
}
```

Then instantiate your enumerable of custom types like so:

```
IEnumerable<MyCustomType> myCustomTypes = from x category in myEntities.Categories
                                          where category.UserId == userId
                                          orderby category.CategoryName
                                          select new MyCustomType { CategoryName = category.CategoryName, UserId = category.UserId };
```

You cannot use IQueryable when doing this as IQueryable allows you to send expression trees to the datasource. myEntities.Categories implements IQueryable so the query we just listed is executed at the source, but further queries on your `IEnumerable<MyCustomType>` Will be executed on the objects in memory.

Comment: Hi I was actually using select new {...} which is an anonymous type. How do I go about casting it to IQueryable? Thanks.

Comment: If you are creating an anonymous type then you cannot cast it, unless that type corresponds with an existing type.

Answer (score 4):

You should use it as an `IQueryable<Category>`, which is its compile-time type.

At runtime, it will be an `ObjectQuery<Category>`.  However, you should not use that.

Comment: Hi I was actually using select new {...} which is an anonymous type. How do I go about casting it to IQueryable? Thanks.

Comment: @Aperture: It's already an `IQueryable<T>`.  You don't need to cast at all.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the other answers, you can also use the `AsQueryable()` method to get an IQueryable object that will have all the usual Linq query methods on it.

Comment: This is true, however it is usually not a true IQueryable and will not translate expression trees into code at the source, such as SQL. Instead it just does it's best to emulate an IQueryable for casting purposes, usually for unit testing. I suggest not using `AsQueryable()` where possible because it can be unstable since it is not really connected to an underlying ORM.